# Approximately how rich is the soil that's permanent-black dirt?

Tags: soil, nutrients

Unless you've dug around in a swamp you probably haven't seen the dirt that's permanently black (or the dirt that's built up over 1000s of years from decomposing plants), so I was wondering how rich the nutrients in that soil is.

Comment: I found out later from my dad that the dirt goes back as grass to the cretaceous period from an excavation that was performed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be pretty rich, but color isn't really an indicator. The super dark color comes from an unusually high carbon content, which itself is good, but not enough to sustain forever.

If you use this soil in a pot, and water properly the free nutrients will mostly drop out as soon as any other soil.